# WebBrowser.DocumentText Property in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, pdf, ms-word, webbrowser-control

I have a browser control, which will be feeted with Text & plots etc.
I looks fine in my browser control.

Now I want to export the browser content to a word file were It can be exported to PDF/HTMl/Doc etc

This works fine for windows forms. I use the WebBrowser1.DocumentText property and write it to a file etc. This is the Command:

```
(System.IO.File.WriteAllText(tempFileName, WebBrowser1.DocumentText)
```

Unfortunaley the WebBrowser.DocumentText Property is no more available in WPF. How Can I solve this problem ?

Here´s is the code for forms:

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.IO


 Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        ' save the document as html, mhtm (embedded), document or pdf
        If dlgSaveDoc.ShowDialog = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            ' create a temp file of the web browser document
            Dim tempFileName As String
            tempFileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() & "\" & Now.ToString().Replace(":", "") & "_RepGen" & ".html"
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(tempFileName, WebBrowser1.DocumentText)

            ' load temp file into word
            Dim oWord As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
            Dim oDoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
            oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            Try
                ' for debug, show word
                oWord.Visible = True

                oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(tempFileName)
                Try
                    ' depending on the file type (extension), set the save format
                    Dim sf As WdSaveFormat
                    Dim ext As String = Path.GetExtension(dlgSaveDoc.FileName).ToUpper()
                    If ext.StartsWith(".HTM") Then sf = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatHTML
                    If ext.StartsWith(".MHT") Then sf = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatWebArchive
                    If ext.StartsWith(".DOC") Then sf = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument
                    If ext.StartsWith(".PDF") Then sf = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF

                    ' save the file from word
                    oDoc.SaveAs2(dlgSaveDoc.FileName, sf)
                Finally
                    oDoc.Close()
                    oDoc = Nothing
                End Try
                oWord.Quit()
            Finally
                oWord = Nothing
                ' cleanup
                If File.Exists(tempFileName) Then File.Delete(tempFileName)
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine ...even Plots etc are no Problem:

I used for WPF:

```
Dim tempFileName As String = "E:test.doc 
Dim doc As Object = browser.Document
Dim htmlText = doc.documentElement.InnerHtml


System.IO.File.WriteAllText(tempFileName, htmlText)
```

instead of (for winforms)

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(tempFileName, WebBrowser1.DocumentText)
```

Answer (score 0):

First add the COM reference Microsoft HTML Object Library:

[image: Screenshot of references]

Then you will be able to look at using `mshtml`:

```
Private Function GetPageContent(ByVal wb As WebBrowser) As String
    Return DirectCast(wb.Document, mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass).body.innerHTML
End Function
```